# Jquery / XML No response when using xml generated from a php file

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I want to load a xml file using Jquery . The xml is generated using a php script (Currently just using echo) My problem is that the file will just not produce and results . My Jquery is listed below

```
          $(document).ready(function()
          {

               $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "phpxml.php",
                 dataType: "xml",
                 success: displayXml
              });

          function displayXml(data){

            $(data).find("sites").each(function() {

              var heading = $(this).find("name").text();

              var output = "<li>";
              output += "<h2>" + heading + "</h2>";
              output += "</li>";
              $("#place-holder").append(output);
            });
          } 

          }); // doc ready

          </head>

          <body>

          <h2> Ajax / Jquery Test </h2>
           <ul id='place-holder'>
           </ul>
         </html>
```

My php file is below which just echos xml. Can anyone offer any suggestions please ?

```
            <?php 

            echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>';

            echo"
            <sites>
                <name>
                   J Smith
                 </name>

                <name>
                   A Coxhead
                 </name>

                <name>
                   D Wilson
                 </name>

            </sites>
            " ; 

            ?>
```

Comment: Did `displayXml` get called? Is there anything written to `#place-holder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that you haven't set content -type in phpxml.php file.

try,

```
<?php 
header('content-type:text/xml');
            echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>';

            echo"
            <sites>
                <name>
                   J Smith
                 </name>

                <name>
                   A Coxhead
                 </name>

                <name>
                   D Wilson
                 </name>

            </sites>
            " ; 

?>
```

Make sure that there should be no spaces before php tag other wise headers will not be sent.

Comment: Content-Type is nessery if you don't put dataType in `$.ajax`

Answer (score 0):

what does Firebug or equivalent tell you about the response?  First things first, is your ajax request getting a response?

also, put a breakpoint (or alert) in your displayXml function to make sure it is firing...

Answer (score 0):

try to add error callback to `$.ajax`.

If this is exacly what your code look like, then you have spaces before `<?` in php file.

xml file must have `<?xml` as first characters

you also don't have `<script type="text/javascript"> ...  </script>` tags